# Regex first character before word

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

> Aida [09/01/2019 11:24:17]: This is just some of the things I can help you with. Aida [09/01/2019 11:24:18]: You can read more detailed descriptions about the processes on the right hand side. Employee   [09/01/2019 11:24:23]: can't log in to bolanAida [09/01/2019 11:24:25]: What is the user ID?Employee   [09/01/2019 11:24:28]: x0000yAida [09/01/2019 11:25:21]: Bolån production account x0000y is now enabled. Aida [09/01/2019 11:25:23]: You can read more detailed descriptions about the processes on the right hand side. Aida [09/01/2019 11:44:43]: This conversation has been closed.

There are few occurences where there is a character before a word like Aida or Employee (no space between words)

> bolanAida, x0000yAida, ID?Employee

and I would like to add spaces between these words in the whole text.

> bolan Aida, x0000y Aida, ID? Employee

Maybe you have any regex ideas on how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you know where one word ends and the next one begins in order to insert a space?

Comment: I need spaces exactly before words Aida or Employee if there are none

Comment: And you have an exhaustive list of these words? If so, you can do it by trying to find those words inside another. But beware that something like "b**aida**rka" might come up as a false positive. If you don't have an exhaustive list, then there is no way to determine where one word ends and where another starts.

Comment: Yes, the list is exhaustive and the only words in the list are Aida and Employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

str = 'Aida Employee bolanAida, x0000yAida, ID?Employee Aida'
print re.sub(r'(?<=\S)(?=Aida|Employee)', ' ', str)
```

**Output:**

```
Aida Employee bolan Aida, x0000y Aida, ID? Employee Aida
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\S)             # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a non space before
(?=Aida|Employee)   # positive look ahead, make sure we have Aida or Employee after
```

[lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 2):

This kind of things can be accomplished with a backreference and a capture group.
Depending on the language you are using, you have to adjust this ruby example:

```
> string = 'bolanAida, x0000yAida, ID?Employee Aida'
 => "bolanAida, x0000yAida, ID?Employee Aida" 
> string.gsub( /(\S)Aida/, '\1 Aida')
 => "bolan Aida, x0000y Aida, ID?Employee Aida"
```

The capture group is (\S), selecting any non-space character. This is backreferenced in ruby with \1, but in other languages this may be $1 or regex-group(1)

Comment: I am trying to do this in python and my line looks like this:
text = re.sub('/(\S)Aida/', '\1 Aida', text)
However, after printing the text words are still not separated. As I checked, in python backreference is \1 as well.

Comment: Hi Karolis, I tried it out in Python, but it works as expected:text = re.sub( "(\S)Aida", '\1 Aida', text)||text = re.sub( "(\S)Aida", '\1 Aida', text)||print text   => bola Aida, x0000 Aida, ID?Employee Aida  Is your test correct?

Comment: I noticed that in your suggestion the regex eats the last character of the preceding word and inserts space instead. So we have 'bola ' where it should be 'bolan', 'x0000 ' where it should be 'x0000y' and so on (it is also seen in your Python output). I've tried this regex in my code and this was the problem for me as well

Comment: oh yes, I see. in pyton, you have to put an r before an string to make it raw, to remove the special meaning form the escape characters . In order to address the first capture group, you have either to use '\\1' or r'\1' .